# Not getting httpd dump on segfault

Tags: freebsd, apache-2.4

I'm attempting to troubleshoot apache seg faults, and am trying to get a core dump for it. I've followed the instructions from [here](http://dready.org/blog/2010/07/04/httpd-exited-on-signal-11-solved/) and still not happening. Here's what I've done so you don't have to read that whole thing.

- `httpd.conf` set `CoreDumpDirectory` to `/tmp/mycoredumps` which exists and is owned by www (the user apache runs as)
- `sysctl kern.coredump` is 1
- set `sysctl.sugid_coredump` to 1 (was 0)
- set `ulimit -c` set to `unlimited`, was 0
- restarted httpd

I did all of the above as root. Got another segfault, went to `/tmp/mycoredumps` and it was empty.

I'm on FreeBSD 8.4 and Apache 2.4

<s>I started thinking, well maybe I need to do the `ulimit` as the actual www user, so I ran `su www --shell /bin/bash --command "ulimit -c"` which said `This account is currently not available`.
[Edit] Appears the message is due to the www user's shell set to nologin</s>
[Edit] Changed the www user's shell over to bash, `su`ed to them and ran `ulimit -c` and it's saying unlimied.

Comment: Have you seen the CoreDump page on the apache wiki? The are specific steps for FreeBSD systems.  https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CoreDump

Comment: Yeah, that was another source of info I used. The only thing in there that I forgot to put in the question was the core dump pattern which is set to %N.dump

Comment: Have you tried to run the server with `strace` (redirecting output to a file)? It will slow it down a lot tho, and the segfault may not happen then.

Comment: @ott-- on amd64 so I used `truss` since `strace` isn't available, and of course the whole time it was running no segfault. I'd still like to figure out why I'm not getting dumps when I should be though.